# Awk pass variable containing columns to be printed

Tags: awk

I want to pass a variable to awk containing which columns to print from a file?

In this trivial case file.txt contains a single line

```
11 22 33 44 55
```

This is what I've tried:

```
awk -v a='2/4' -v b='$2/$4' '{print a"\n"$a"\n"b"\n"$b}' file.txt
```

output:

```
2/4
22
$2/$4
11 22 33 44 55
```

desired output:

```
0.5
```

Is there any way to do this type of "eval" of variable as a command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method for dividing columns specified in variables:

```
$ awk -v num=2 -v denom=4 '{print $num/$denom}' file.txt
0.5
```

If you trust the person who creates the shell variable `b`, then here is a method that offers flexibility:

```
$ b='$2/$4'; awk "{print $b}" file.txt
0.5
$ b='$1*$2'; awk "{print $b}" file.txt
242
$ b='$2,$2/$4,$5'; awk "{print $b}" file.txt
22 0.5 55
```

The flexibility here is due to the fact that `b` can contain any `awk` code.  This approach requires that you trust the creator of `b`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what about if the columns to print are in an array: e.g.  `awk -v a='$2 $2/$4 $5' 'BEGIN{split(a,b," ")}{for (i=1;i<=length(b);i++) printf b[i]" "}' file.txt`

Comment: @Patrick Have a look at the new example to the answer and let me know if that is what you need.